# Big query Parse Error in Appscript when using insertAll

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to use the [insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll) parameter to insert data in a big query table. To parse it properly in json, here is the method which I am using

```
var datasetId = 'XXXXXXX';
var tableId = 'XXXXXX';
var rowobjects = [];
var rowData = {};
rowData.ldap = ldap;
rowData.avgrating = rating;
rowData.emails = 0;
rowData.jediemails = 0;
rowobjects.push(rowData);
Logger.log(rowobjects);
var rjob = BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll(ProjectID, datasetId, tableId, rowobjects);
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePZ5O.png). I am not sure how am I not parsing it properly. I hope someone can suggest how this needs to be parsed.

Comment: That was a typo. Sorry! I'm still struggling with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with AppScript, but I should point out that it looks like your row objects are dictionaries that match the schema of your table. The insertAll API takes "insertion rows" which have an "insertId" field used to uniquely identify rows for duplicate removal on request retries, and a "json" field that should point to a dictionary that matches your schema.

Perhaps your code should look more like:

```
var rowData = {};
rowData.insertId = <some deduplication id for retries>;
rowData.json = {};
rowData.json.ldap = ldap;
rowData.json.avgrating = rating;
rowData.json.emails = 0;
rowData.json.jediemails = 0;
rowobjects.push(rowData);
```

In fact, if the final parameter of the insertAll is intended to match the body of the request, then you should instead be populating a dictionary with a property "rows" that points to the above rowobjects, with other parameters set as necessary (see the insertAll link in your question).

FINAL EDIT I SWEAR:

Based on [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined) section:

In addition to passing a dictionary that matches the body of the insertAll request (described in the "request body" section [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll)), your parameters should be in the following order:

```
insertAll(requestBody, projectId, datasetId, tableId)
```

Comment: I changed the code to what you suggest but I am still getting the same error. I did try changing the order of parameters but then it starts giving me an error which says "No rows present in the request". 
I am not sure what kind of parsing it is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the actual issue, but in the last line of your code, you are trying to use a variable that does not exist due to a space -

```
var rjob = BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll(ProjectID, datasetId, tableId, row objects);
```

should be

```
var rjob = BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll(ProjectID, datasetId, tableId, rowobjects);
```

to pass the `rowobjects` array to the insertAll function. Let me know if this solves your issue!